# Unable to find xPath in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

i have had no problem finding objects on the webpages, but this one is giving me hard time

url used: https://interact2.responsys.net/authentication/login/LoginPage

on this page i am unable to click the "Sign In" button.

I tried with ID, Class, xPath, custom xPath

Firepath : Sign In

where am i going wrong? could you please help me

Comment: Please share the exact html of the "Sign In" button, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: button id="signIn" type="submit" style="margin-right:20px;" class="buttonOn">Sign In</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are two elements on page with nearly the same `HTML` code. The first one is hidden, so no matter how you try to click the button using `id` or `class`... you'll get `ElementNotVisibleException`. You need to use index to select required one (second one), e.g. on `Python` this should be something like

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("signIn")[1].click()
```

or you might use `onclick` attribute which contained only in second element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='signIn' and @onclick]").click()
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson. 
As i was using Java , i tried with "//button[@id='signIn' and @onclick]"
It worked

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   JavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +"evt.initMouseEvent('click',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false,false, false, 0,null);" + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);", driver.FindElement(By.Id("signIn")));
```

Comment: is it working? always helped me when element not visible or clickable.

Comment: great! I thought my question was helpful! is it not the best answer? :)

Comment: I got so excited when I got bump up in my reputation :) sadly it was not for long..

Comment: ah! hey so sorry buddy